# What is nHibernate CollectionProxy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nhibernate, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to understand the [CollectionProxy](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.Alpha1/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/DebugHelpers/CollectionProxy.cs) exposed in nHibernate. Is it just an extension for ICollection to return a list collection, if so why a proxy pattern is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing is the Visual Studie extensibility eco-system. Firstly, as we can see, this class is in namespaces:

```
namespace NHibernate.DebugHelpers
```

And that means, it is only for **debug purposes**.

#### How it works?

Well firstly we can see that there is some attribute declaration over `public object[] Items` like this:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
public object[] Items
{
  ..
```

And this is instrcuting Visual Studio debugger to:

> Hide a Root when observing the collection *(as the enum name says)*. Effectively, it will save a line in a debug window. We will see just items of that collection...

#### How to hook it on?

Just use this helper as another attribute declaration e.g. as here on a [PersistentGenericBag](https://github.com/juanplopes/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Collection/Generic/PersistentGenericBag.cs#L20):

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof (CollectionProxy<>))]
public class PersistentGenericBag<T> : PersistentBag, IList<T>
```

...that's it... nothing special... just a feature of the Visual Studio extensibility framework...

Comment: Now I see similar patterns being used in XAML where Proxy objects are provided for the design apps like Blend. During the runtime, the proxies are not used.